# Is there an easy way to remove blank objects from a has-many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got the following models:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :external_ids, as: :identifiable, dependent: :destroy, validate: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :external_ids
end
```

and this one:

```
class ExternalId < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :identifiable, polymorphic: true

  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :identifiable, presence: true, on: :create
end
```

Because of a nested form in the course form-view it's possible that a blank object of an external id will be saved. I'd like to remove these blank objects. With "blank object" I mean an `ExternalId` which is a new record and has a blank name. Currently I do that as follows:

```
    @course.attributes = course_params
    ## SNIP - workaround to fix validations
    external_ids = []
    @course.external_ids.each do |ext_id|
      external_ids << ext_id unless(ext_id.new_record? && ext_id.name.blank?)
    end
    @course.external_ids = external_ids
    ## SNAP - workaround to fix validations
    @course.save
```

But this is a lot of code for a very simple task. Is there any function for that? `destroy_if` doesn't exists for an association, only for arrays.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` with such key

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :external_ids, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['name'].blank? }
```

From [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods-label-One-to-many):

> You may also set a `:reject_if` proc to silently ignore any new record hashes if they fail to pass your criteria